# Cucumber Runner class throws unsecured http url TestNGException, however my .feature files and testng.xml will run the suite without issues

Tags: java, http, jvm, cucumber, testng

When I run my cucumber test suite using my TestRunner class (the class where my @CucumberOptions, glue and tags are located) I get this error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
TestNG by default disables loading DTD from unsecured Urls. If you need to explicitly load the DTD from a http url, please do so by using the JVM argument [-Dtestng.dtd.http=true]
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.resolveEntity(TestNGContentHandler.java:115)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:111)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:1025)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1142)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1040)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:943)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:162)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:248)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:322)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:374)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

However, when I run the tests using the .feature files or my testng.xml file there are no issues and the test suite runs as expected. My issue is that I would like to share this suite with others without them having to manually add the JVM argument in their VM Options.

This is what my pom.xml looks like where the maven compiler and surefire plugin are concerned:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <testng.dtd.http>true</testng.dtd.http>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

As you can see I have also already set the systemPropertyVariable under the surefire plugin which should have resolved the http error. Here is what my Runner class looks like:

```
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = { "src/test/java/Features" },
        glue = { "StepDefinitions" },
        tags = "@First or @Middle or @Last"
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this happens  when you have xml schema configuration specified to implement some features using the namespaces.

Earlier, some of the organization had namespaces uri with http instead of https.

Find an alternative uri for the same schema in https.

For instance:-
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="**http**://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">